# How can I do profiling for my EXE developed with Visual Studio 2005 on my user's machine?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, profiling

I am using Visual Studio 2005 to develop C++ standalone application. On one of my users' computer, my program is performing really badly. It runs slow, some iterations of a particular loop take an unusually long time to complete, etc. I have saved the symbol (PDB file) of my EXE for the build that my user is using.

Now, I want to know if there is a way I can start profiling the performance of this EXE when the user starts using it. I can request the user to run the profiler and my EXE together. I am looking for some kind of tool that starts profiling it, writes all profile-data into a file and then I should be able to use that file along with my PDB function to learn how much time was spent in which function. In this way, I will be able to identify which function was causing the bottleneck.

Is there such a tool available?

Comment: Which profiling tool do you use? Why is it not good enough for profiling on your user's machine? (i use [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/))

Comment: @anatolyg I am using VerySleepy. But it is unable to display all the function names in the call stack. For the same EXE, it is able to display many function names in the call stack while many of them just appear as hexadecimal numbers, e.g. [600CB989].

Comment: If its hex-numbers it's most likely that it's in code that doesn't have debug info, like system libraries.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have debug symbols for everything including the system libraries. Also, as I have mentioned before, the hex numbers are shown for my EXE, not Windows DLLs.